# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to migrate my app to Material 3, but the switches seems to crash the app, spitting the error present in the title. The switch only has the width and height attributes, both set to wrap_content.

Log:

```
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:474)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.makeLayout(SwitchCompat.java:995)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.onMeasure(SwitchCompat.java:916)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1608)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1240)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:723)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1608)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:878)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:260)
at com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView.onMeasure(MaterialCardView.java:206)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1608)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:878)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1792)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:627)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1156)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1608)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:878)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1608)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:878)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6981)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:760)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26380)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2637)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2943)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2350)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9198)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1231)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:832)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7925)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

I have no idea what I have done wrong, the internet doesn't seem helpful. The switch also doesn't seem to render in Android Studio either.

The dependency is updated to 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'

I am building off the same theme I am using for Material 2, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Material 3 Themes in the `android:theme` attribute in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, you can try `Theme.Material3.Light` or `Theme.Material3.DayNight`.